# Environment variable not working with Mapbox token on NextJS

Tags: environment-variables, next.js

I have a Mapbox map which I am trying to pass an environment variable in to using the built-in `.env.local` integration in NextJS 9.4. As per the Next docs, I am using a `.env.local` file and in order to expose the env variable to the browser, I am prefixing it with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. However, the access token is not being passed through with this setup. When I pass the token in directly, it does work, so I know this is some sort of problem with the `.env.local` file not passing that particular env variable, even though it does with other tokens.

.env.local:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_TOKEN=my_mapbox_access_token
OTHER_API_TOKEN=my_other_api_token
```

map.js:

```
// Works
mapboxgl.accessToken = "my_mapbox_access_token";

// Doesn't work
mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_TOKEN;
```

other.js:

```
// Also works
class OtherAPI extends RESTDataSource {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.baseURL = "https://rest.otherapi.com/";
    }

    willSendRequest(request) {
        request.headers.set(
            "X-Application-Key",
            process.env.OTHER_API_TOKEN
        );
    }...
```

So the Mapbox token works when it is passed directly, and the environment variables work when used with other APIs, but for some reason the env variables are not working with the Mapbox API. I've tried with and without the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this

You are using `dotenv`

Please see this discussion on GitHub:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12754

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: I am not using dotenv and still having the same problem

Comment: @Wayne The above GitHub-thread is still open, hence you may post a question there. BR